# grails jquery auto update div with fetching from DB

Tags: jquery, grails

I have a set that is displayed in a html page, using `<g:each>`, inside a div with, for example, class="class1".

The content of the set if fetched in a controller and passed to the html page in session.someVariableName.

And i need to update this div every 10 seconds.

**How do i implement something like that?**

I have a jquery script that works correctly, like this:

```
 $(document).ready(
            function() {
                setInterval(function() {
                    $('.class1').toggle();
                }, 10000);
            });
```

It correctly toggles visibility of the needed div every 10 seconds.

I learnt that to update i have to use function .load(). But how do i implement this particular functionality? I searched everywhere and couldn't find something related to my problem.

Do i need to implement an additional controller that produces a view with only the needed div and point the .load() function to this view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this! With help of joshm76 from #grails on freenode.

There are several steps to solve this:

1. i need a template with the div contents i need to update
2. i need a controller that with a model passes needed values to the template
3. i need to include this inside the div i want to update with a
4. with jquery i update the div contents

1) Template is a .gsp file with _ before the name, like `_myTemplate.gsp`. Put it in the view folder of the controller you will be using.

2)

```
    def action(){
    def var
    //some logic to populate the variable

    Map model = [myVar: var]
    render(template: '_myTemplate', model: model)
}
```

in the template the variable can be accessed with `${myVar}`

3) inside the div you need to update, put the `<g:include>` instead of the content you had there before (now the content is in the template)

```
<g:include controller='controller' action='action' />
```

4) the jquery part (fetches the template every 5 seconds):

```
    $(document).ready(
            function() {
                setInterval(function() { 
                $('#divId').load('/app/controller/action');
                }, 5000);
            });
```

you can also use the $.get() function, the result seems to be identical

Comment: By this approach, page seems to be refreshed all the time whenever the div is updated. Page doesn't refresh in actual but a blink is seen in the page every time div is updated. Can we ignore this blink? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unsure if this helps, your question was not so clear - you could run a jquery get that updates the div with its output, rather than .html you could also use .append( which appends to the content.

```
 $(document).ready(
            function() {
                setInterval(function() {


                     $.get("/"+baseapp+"/controller/action?id="+id+"&two="+two,function(data){
                            $('.class1').html(data).fadeIn('slow');
                    });
                }, 10000);
            });
```

take a look at jssh plugin using both ajax/websockets to do something of a similar sort to your q.